# Notation of all intervals on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: notation

Is there any concise way how to define/denote the set of all intervals on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $\{[a,b]\mid a<b\}$

Comment: Closed and open? Finite and infinite?

Comment: finite, left closed, right open

Comment: There is no common convention for this because there is no need for a extra symbol in general. In some works it could make sense to define extra symbols for special needs. The main problem is that there are so many possible configurations of intervals that one might to restrict to. Its easier to say 'Let $I=$.. be such and such..' ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use $\left\{\left[a,b\right)|a,b\in\Bbb R\right\}$ or perhaps you could write in terms of the function $f:\Bbb R^2\to\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$ that maps the pair $(a,b)$ to the interval $[a,b)$.